# How to trigger rebuild in travis during the travis build

Tags: travis-ci

Is it possible to trigger a rebuild of the master branch inside the scripts travis executes from the `.travis.yml` file.

So I want to trigger a rebuild if something happens during the build.
(For example only dependcies got cached and the source has not been build)

Somthing like: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds
but this needs an autho. token. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that needs an auth token you can add that as an [encrypted environment variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Encrypted-Variables) to your build and as long as you don't `echo` or similar the var, you would be fine.